# Kiel traduki “(to) have the moves”?

Tags: translation

Kio estas bona traduko por "to have the moves"? Gravas por la traduko, ke "moves" restu substantivo. "Moves" rilate al dancado aŭ ĝenerale al sporto.

---

What's a good translation of *to have the moves*? It's important in the context, that *moves* shall be translated as a noun.

Perhaps you could also also clarify if there are any ambiguous meanings in the English phrase, and perhaps include them in your translation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> you have the moves = vi regas la movojn

Here *have* means *akiris* and *posedas*+*povas fari* means *scipovas*, which is expressed by *regas*.

Instead of the very general *moves* (*dancmovojn*) one might consider other terms, but there is no need. *Paŝojn* stresses a totally different aspect, for example.

Answer (score 7):

"To have the moves" means to have memorized, and gained competence in, the movements required for a dance; it is informal and cannot really be used in other contexts (except maybe some sports or martial arts). In English, *a move* can mean an action in a boardgame, or in a conflict, or the act of moving house; however, none of these can be "had".

You can say ***scii la movojn*** which means "to know the moves, have the moves in one's repertoire" as opposed to *koni la movojn* which means "to be familiar with the moves". (Note that *scii* may be stronger or weaker than *koni* depending on the context: *scii personon* means "to know of (the existence of) a person".)

---

*To have the moves* signifas parkerigon de, kaj lertiĝon pri, la movoj bezonataj por danco; la esprimo estas neformala kaj ne estas uzata en aliaj kuntekstoj (eble krom iuj sportoj kaj batalartoj). En la angla, *a move* povas aludi agon en tabulludo, aŭ en intrigo, aŭ agon transloĝiĝi; tamen, neniu el tiuj povas esti *havata*.

Vi povas diri ***scii la movojn***, kiu signifas "havi la movojn en repertuaro" kontraste al *koni la movojn* kiu signifas "pasiginti iom da tempo per zorga atento al la movoj". (Rimarku ke *scii* povas esti aŭ pli forta aŭ pli malforta ol *koni* laŭ kunteksto: *scii personon* signifas "esti konscia de la ekzistado de persono".)

- *lerta* — skilled, clever

  - *lertiĝi* — to become skilled
- *movi manon, piedon* — to move a hand, a foot

  - *movo* — movement [in general]
- *moviĝi* — to move [intransitive]

  - *moviĝo* — movement (of self, esp. whole body)